# Embedding image in html body want show as well

Tags: c#, html, email, email-attachments, document-body

I need to send mail with which have mixture of pictures and texts. My problem is that can't send image inside of body, it always appear at bottom op body.

So my question is **how to send write position picture inside of email body**?

Here is code which don't work as well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mime;
using WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        string To;

        To = Properties.Settings.Default.To.ToString();

        msg.To.Add("some.name@gmail.com");
        msg.From = new MailAddress("your.adress@gmail.com");
        msg.Subject = "Subject";

        string path = "C:\\root.jpg"; // my logo is placed in images folder

        LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
        logo.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

        //now do the HTML formatting
        AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
              "<html><body>" + "<p>This will have to be before picture</p>" + "<img src=cid:companylogo/>" + "<p>This will have to be after pictures.</p>" +
              "<br></body></html>",
              null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        //now add the AlternateView
        av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

        //now append it to the body of the mail
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        smtp.Port = 587;

        //for gmail
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
             "your.adress@gmail.com",
             "password");

        smtp.Send(msg);
    }
}
}
```

I tested on gmail client and here is what i get:

[image]

Comment: What email client(s) have you tested this with? Try posting the full original output as well?

Comment: i use gmail client ... see update of question

Comment: And you're displaying images within Gmail? Or added it to the safe sender list?

Comment: I display it with gmail, and it's look ecsactlly as on below picture